# Why do my buttons change position in Chrome with media queries?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Currently I am working on a project mostly HTML and CSS. I have two buttons in the middle of the page, positioned absolute. They appear correct in Firefox, but in Google Chrome the buttons position randomly to the left. It changes the position to the left with each refresh. This bug does not appear when the responsive CSS sheet is turned off.

I hope you guys can help me out, because it is an very annoying bug :S

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not using `position: relative` on the elements containing the absolutely positioned elements.

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/